# How to make Google OAuth button impersonalized

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, google-oauth

I have a Google OAuth button using [@react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) (the npm package).
This button works fine. The problem comes when you're logged in on Google in your browser and then you view the button. Instead of showing "Sign up with Google" it will say "Sign in as {google_name}".
I don't want this to happen I want it to always say "Sign up with Google".
This is my code

```
<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="MY CLIENT ID">
    <GoogleLogin
        type="standard"
        text="signin_with"
        width={250}
        onSuccess={(credentialResponse) => {
            changeGoogleEmail(credentialResponse);
        }}
    />
   <br />
</GoogleOAuthProvider>
```

I have looked through the @react-oauth/google docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) to see if there's a property for disabling this but I haven't found one. I've also tried switching to the version which uses HTML like this

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
    data-login_uri="https://your.domain/your_login_endpoint"
    data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin"
    data-type="standard"
    data-size="large"
    data-theme="outline"
    data-text="sign_in_with"
    data-shape="rectangular"
   data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

If you choose to give me answer using the plain HTML could you also provide an answer on how to create a callback for when this is finished.

[image: How I want it to look]
[image: How it looks currently]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function:

```
const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: codeResponse => console.log(codeResponse)
});
```

Make a custom button and call it.

You can then get the data by making a fetch request like this:

```
await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You would use the `data-context` attribute on your `g_id_onload` to show which text you want.

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
    data-login_uri="https://your.domain/your_login_endpoint"
    data-auto_prompt="false"
    data-context="signup">
</div>
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-context

Comment: Sorry  I just realised it only works when the data client id isn't a real value because when I change it to my actual client ID it shows the log in saying sign in as Jesse or whatever your Google name is instead of always being sign up/in with Google. Also can you try and do it by using the npm package if possible